# Expecting end of string error caused by <<)>> in wiql when getting Work items inTFS?

Tags: c#, string, tfs, azure-devops, wiql

this my below query and i am getting the error 
**Expecting  end of string error caused by <<)>>**

code :

```
string querystring = string.Format("select [System.ID],[System.WorkitemType],[System.Title],[System.State],[System.AssigendTo],[Microsoft.VSTS.StoryPoints]," +
                "[Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priorty],[System.iterationPath]"+
                " FROM WorkitemLinks" +
                " WHERE" +
                " (Source.[System.TeamProject]='{0}'" +
                " and Source.[System.IterationPath]='MRI_SCRUM_GIT\\Pluse Pheonix\\Sprint 1'" +
                " and Source.[System.WorkitemType]='User Story' " +
                " or Source.[System.WorkitemType]='Task'))" +
                " and [System.Links.LinkType]='System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Forward'" +
                " Target.[System.WorkItemType] <> 'Task' " +
                " ORDER BY [Microsoft.VSTS.Common.StackRank]," +
                " [Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priorty]" +
                " mode (Recursive)", projectname);

             Query treequery = new Query(workItemStore, querystring);
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I see you are missing one one brace in your query use

```
and (Source.[System.WorkitemType]='User Story'  
or Source.[System.WorkitemType]='Task'))
```

instead of

```
and Source.[System.WorkitemType]='User Story'  
or Source.[System.WorkitemType]='Task'))
```

Comment: now i am getting Expecting end of string. The error is caused by «Target».'

Comment: you don't have operator in front of Target. it should be ...'and Target'...